# How to set Alarm Tone from My Application?

Tags: android

How to set Alarm Tone from My Application?

The Main Problem is I am Set Alarm More then one time but only second alarm is working, sorry for bad English.

Thanks in advance.

```
if(day.equals("Daily")){
    System.out.println("Daily Alarm");
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() +(seconds * 1000) , (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ,pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set for Daily", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    System.out.println("Weekly Alarm");
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() +(seconds * 1000) , (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ,pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set for "+day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

following code I used for Pick tone:-

```
String uri = null;
intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");

if (uri != null) {
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,Uri.parse(uri));
} else {
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,(Uri) null);
}
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

startActivityForResult Method :-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            if (uri != null) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String ringTonePath = uri.toString();
            }
        }
}
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i1 = new Intent("com.android.MY_ACTION_A") //Scheduled 1st using a PendingIntent
Intent i2 = new Intent("com.android.MY_ACTION_B") //Scheduled 2st using a PendingIntent
```

If you use the same component (IntentSender - your Activity, Service) to schedule the alarm, only the most recent one will work. In the above case **i1** will be cancelled.

Comment: so what is the solution of this Problem?

Comment: if i use different pendingintent for both daily & weekly it will work or not?